# Why does listFiles() not guarantee order?

Tags: java, file

[This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29) seems like a strange thing to say.

> There is no guarantee that the name strings in the resulting array
>   will appear in any specific order; they are not, in particular,
>   guaranteed to appear in alphabetical order.

Why can't the order be guaranteed? What one gets when one `ls` could, for example be a reasonable default.

Is this something that was decided for (performance?) reason, or perhaps where is some deeper truth out there?

Comment: Please answer this question: Just what *is* the "natural" order of a list of files? The file name? The date it was added? The type? Size?

Comment: `ls does sort the names internally.

Comment: `ls` sorts the names internally unless you tell it to do otherwise. `dir` on Windows doesn't, unless you tell it to do so. How do you define "order"? Your idea of what the right order is might not be mine or anyone else's - is it name, size, creation date, CRC, attribute?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no natural order that files gravitate toward.  If you say alphabetic, then with which locale/collating sequence?  Do all OSes that java runs on support that order intrinsically?  If not, then the API would need to resort whatever was received from the OS.  Since it is likely that you the API client 1) may not care or 2) will want something different, it makes much more sense to just deliver the files with no guaranteed order rather than doing a wasted sort.  If you care, you can do the sort.

Comment: +1 Giving you the order given by the OS is the most sensible order IMHO, anything else you can sort your own way.